# AWS ElasticBeanstalk: JWT token not being validated after configuration change

Tags: django, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Using AWS console, I changed configuration setting of api key for a third-party service. Then all of a sudden, the following error is popping up on my live server.

`{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}`

It seems `JWT token` is not being validated(or passed). After hours of googling, I found that the error is caused by `EB apache setting`

Apparently, by setting,

```
container_commands:
01_wsgipass:
command: 'echo "WSGIPassAuthorization On" >> ../wsgi.conf'
```

in `*.config`, the problem should go away. I did exactly the same, with the code in `wgsi_enabled_pass.config` created within `.ebextensions` but it is still not working.

Please help the newbie pros! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, were you able to fix it? If yes, you can post it as your own answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @nbeuchat I posted my anwer below. Let me know if this works

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, were you able to fix it? If yes, can you please post the solution with some description?

Comment: @Devansh It's been some time since I posted this. So I don't exactly remember how I fixed it. But I think the fix was to restart the app from EBS console, as I commented below. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to a `.ebextensions/customize_httpd.config` file:

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi_custom.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

This is more reliable then trying to concat to a conf file that may or may not exist.

Answer (score 1):

@nbeuchat

If I rememeber correctly, try restarting the app from EBS console, or re-deploy the codes AFTER setting the container_commands in *.config as in the question. If this does not fix the problem, let me know. I'll look into what I did in the past to fix the bug.